# How do I replace unknown characters in a string? Wildcard?

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I have a string .. let's say:

```
string MyString = "SELECT Stuff FROM Table WHERE Code = "Foo" AND DATE=20120101";
```

I want to replace `20120101` with a `?`. But, the `20120101` string I search for won't always be the same. It will always start with a `2`, and always contain 8 characters. It may be 20121225, 20130510, etc.

Can I use wildcards somehow? As in:

```
string Fixed = MyString.Replace("2*******", "?");
```

What I'm looking for is this result:

```
MyString = "SELECT Stuff FROM Table WHERE Code = "Foo" AND DATE=?";
```

Comment: Can you tackle the problem nearer to the cause? Where have you got this string from in the first place?

Comment: the string is a SQL query that is cut and pasted from MS Access into a textbox. I need to replace the date with a ? so I can use a parameterized query. I have other stuff going on too, to convert the format from SQL to DB2 (replace * with % for example)

Comment: Please show `MyString` in the form you would like it after the requested replacement.

Comment: I updated my question .. hope it helps

Comment: I just re-read your question... you just need to do `MyString.Replace("[0-9]{6}","?")`.  That will replace each instance of a 6 digit number with a single `?`.  If you want to kinda smartly filter for dates: `[12][089][0-9][0-9]`.

Comment: I just re-read your question... you just need to do `MyString.Replace("[0-9]{8}","?")`.  That will replace each instance of a 6 digit number with a single `?`.  If you want to kinda smartly filter for dates: `[12][089][0-9][0-9][01][012][0-3][0-9]`.

Comment: @BaileyS, that doesn't seem to work. Does it matter that the date string format I'm looking for is YYYYMMDD (ie: 20120101)?

Comment: Are you using regex from the second comment?  The first example would match any 8 consecutive digits, and replace them with `?`.  The second regex is where it would matter the order of YYYYMMDD, because it does not allow illogical digits in each position.  Unfortunately, I did a kinda sloppy job for you :(.  Try this one instead: `MyString.Replace("[12][089][0-9][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]","?")`.  The error was that it would only allow the months 01,02,10,11,12 before.  If you want a really robust solution you can use regex alternatives too, but I dunno if they are supported in C#?

Comment: AH! ok, I understand what this is doing now. It wasn't clicking earlier, that each number/range in the brackets represented a single character in an 8 character string.. I did end up using regex, but thank you for showing me how to do it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string Fixed = Regex.Replace( MyString, @"DATE=2\d{7}", "DATE=?" );
```

Or alternatively, using a positive look-behind

```
 Replace( MyString, @"(?<=DATE=)2\d{7}", "?" );
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use RegEx:

```
Regex.Replace(input,@"DATE=""\d*""", "?");
```

However, if this is a SQL query, it would be better to use a parameterized query to avoid SQL injection attacks and so forth. It's the industry standard way of doing these kinds of things.

Comment: He does not want to replace all of the digits with ?, only some of them.

Comment: @BaileyS `I want to replace 20120101 with a ?`. I believe he wants to replace the entire string with a ?, which is what this will do.

Comment: Sorry, I clarified my original question. The 20120101 will always start with a 2, and always be 8 characters in length.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Regex replace method:

```
    string oldstring = "20120101";
    string newstring = Regex.Replace(oldstring, @"^2[0-9]{7}", "?");
```

Comment: you dont need to use `^`.This wont replace the required string

Answer (score 0):

So is this what you are looking for?

`string MyString = "SELECT Stuff FROM Table WHERE Code = {0} AND DATE={1}";`

This will allow you to use the same string with whatever you want in {0} and {1} with something like:

`String.Format(MyString, codeString, dateString);`

You can reuse the query string with whichever parameters you'd like.

Comment: That's what I'm looking to do, however the user enters a SQL query string that they copy and paste from Access. I want to programmatically turn their query string into a parameterized string.

Comment: That makes sense. Keep in mind that if instead of replacing the sections with '?' you can replace them with {0}, ..., {n}. Then the string will already be in a parameterized format that can be populated with String.Format.

Comment: I'll look into String.Format .. I've been using Parameters.AddWithValue.